# New Facebook Pages Timeline API

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

Facebook released today (Feb 29) Timeline for Pages. It provides private messaging between fans and the organization.

Is there a way to access these messages?

Comment: This might be a good question for the Official Developers Group - http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as of March 29 this API became available. It's working well. Check FB's API documentation.

Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#conversations